# How to get next input element id by using class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to get next textbox id on change event of the first textbox using jquery.
How can i get that. I have used next() for that but its not working as i wanted.

Here is my code,

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>PF Value</p><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox1" class="txtfill" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$bcr$bcr$TextBox1$textbox1" class="txtSec80CCD" value="0" id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox1_textbox1" onblur="calcDedSecCCD(this)"  style="width: 70px;" type="text">
                    <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox1_valCustom" style="color: Red; display: none;">*</span>
                    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox1_ErrorDiv" class="ValidatorErrorDiv" style="display:none">
                        <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox1_Label1">You must enter a <br>number</span>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox2" class="txtfill" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$bcr$bcr$TextBox2$textbox1" class="txtSec80CCD" value="0" id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox2_textbox1" style="width: 70px;" type="text">
                    <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox2_valCustom" style="color: Red; display: none;">*</span>
                    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox2_ErrorDiv" class="ValidatorErrorDiv" style="display:none">
                        <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox2_Label1">You must enter a <br>number</span>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Life Insurance Premium</p><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox3" class="txtfill" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$bcr$bcr$TextBox3$textbox1" class="txtSec80CCD" value="0" id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox3_textbox1" onblur="calcDedSecCCD(this)"  style="width: 70px;" type="text">
                    <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox3_valCustom" style="color: Red; display: none;">*</span>
                    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox3_ErrorDiv" class="ValidatorErrorDiv" style="display:none">
                        <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox3_Label1">You must enter a <br>number</span>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox4" class="txtfill" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$bcr$bcr$TextBox4$textbox1" class="txtSec80CCD" value="0" id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox4_textbox1" style="width: 70px;" type="text">
                    <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox4_valCustom" style="color: Red; display: none;">*</span>
                    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox4_ErrorDiv" class="ValidatorErrorDiv" style="display:none">
                        <span id="ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox4_Label1">You must enter a <br>number</span>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>

   ......
   ......
   ......

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have written my script like this,

```
function calcDedSecCCD(id) {

        var eid = $(id).attr('id');
        //var elementVal = $('#' + eid).val();    
        //var nxtEid = $(eid).next(':input .txtSec80CCD').attr('id');            

        var nextele = $(this + ':input .txtSec80CCD').next();
        //alert(nextele);
        var nextId = $(nextele).attr('id');


        alert("First Element: "+eid);
        alert("First Element: " + nextId);

    }
```

[image]

I want textbox id : ctl00$ctl00$bcr$bcr$TextBox2$textbox1 on change event of textbox1.
How can i get the id of text input using class.
Or any other way to get id of next textbox on change of first one.

Comment: @gdoron: check formatted code and give me some solution!

Comment: It's still very hard to understand what you need, can you please rephrase?

Comment: as showing in image i have two text boxes in a PF value row. I want to set entered value of textbox1 into textbox2. For this purpose i want textbox2's id on change event of textbox1. Same applies to remaining rows. I am calling calcDedSecCCD(id) on changeof textbox1. and i am getting id of first textbox and from this id by using next() i want id of second textbox. Hope you get what i want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written your markup so that it is too hard to read. In time you will you come to appreciate short ID's, names etc. as there is no need to use 40 characters in every selector, it just makes it hard to write javascript and css, and even harder to read and understand the code later.

You've also managed to create an elaborate system of nested elements that are almost certainly unnecessary, and hard to traverse with javascript, keeping it more simple is usually a good idea.

First of, you should probably not pass "id" as a variable to your function, as "id" actually does something in javascript (it gets the elements id, see below script).

If it's only within each "td" you are looking for the next input element, the below will work, but it will not work for the last input in a "td" to find the next input that is within the next "tr" etc.

```
function calcDedSecCCD(elm) {
    var eid = elm.id;
    var nextId = $(elm).parents('td').next().find('input')[0].id;

    alert("First Element: "+eid);
    alert("Next Element: "+nextId);
}
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/MgZaV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You might use the jquery index function

```
var $spans = $("td>span.txtfill");

// Your next function
function get_next_span(elem){

  var $span = $(elem).closest('td>span.txtfill'),
      index = $spans.index($span);

  return $spans.eq(index+1);
}
```

So if you had a text field you would use the helper function like this:

```
var $current = $("#ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_TextBox2_textbox1"),
    $next = get_next_span($current).find('input[type=text]');
```

Or in a change event:

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function(){
   get_next_span(this).find('input[type=text]').show();
});
```